# Can't start Android Studio (when it already worked a lot of times)

Tags: android, android-studio, startup

When I wanted to start working on my app again in Android Studio I had this problem that Android Studio would start, but doesn't show a screen. In my Windows 10 taskbar I can see that it runs: [Android Studio is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGHjW.png). But it doesn't show a window and it isn't on any other desktop. When I Windows+Tab or Alt+Tab it shows just a white screen for Android Studio. I tried restarting Android Studio, restarting my computer, reinstalling Android Studio and none of these worked this time. Yesterday it worked just fine. I had this problem last week too, but reinstalling worked. Does anybody have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I currently have this problem and nothing is working atm..

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when I Upgrade to 4.0.

Reinstalling application is a waste of time, and it may not work.

You can try to delete the configuration file, its directory is named `.AndroidStudio[version]` and it is located by default on win10：

```
C:\Users\[userName]\.AndroidStudio[version]
```

This operation can make it work successfully on my win10.

Hopefully it helped you.

Comment: I'll let you know if it worked the next time I get the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before,

> You can try to delete the configuration file, its directory is named .AndroidStudio[version] and it is located by default on win10：
>
> C:\Users[userName].AndroidStudio[version]

Doing this will probally work, but it will erase all your configurations of the IDE, I learned that if you delete only the file named **recentProjects** found in `C:\Users\[userName]\.AndroidStudio[version]\config\options` it works.